# Can I put all the information for a DocuSign envelope into a Word document without using the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to mark up an MS Word document with all of the information necessary to upload to DocuSign. Specifically, I want to include all the information required for the DocuSign envelope, and also the places where the signatures need to go. I then want to upload that document, either via the API, or the DocuSign web site, and not have any further need to specify the envelope or the signature locations - I would like my markup to be recognised by DocuSign and acted on without any further interaction. It would, of course, mean that there needs to be some way of conveying to DocuSign what this markup is, or else to conform to some pre-defined DocuSign markup.

I have spoken to DocuSign support and they don't really understand the question, but maybe someone here has tried it, or can give a definitive answer as to whether I am asking for a feature that does or does not exist.

If that feature is not there, then we will build it using the DocuSign API, but if there is a wheel, we don't want to reinvent it.

Comment: Answered below. If it helped out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions I can offer you: (1) You could make use of the [DocuSign template feature](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/templates). In my opinion, this is the path of least resistance. (2) You could also provide your document in html markup by leveraging our [responsive signing feature](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview).

**Creating and sending a DocuSign Template:**

First, you can create your template in the DocuSign UI. I suggest this over the API because it very clearly illustrates the variety of features and functions you can enable. You'll also get a good sense of what your end-user will see. Once you have your template created, we will reference it repeatedly later using the API.

To build your first template:

1. Log into your [docusign demo account](https://demo.docusign.net/).
2. Navigate to "Templates" and create a new template
3. Upload your word document and populate the other information
4. Add Recipient roles to your envelope (Ex. Legal, Hiring Manager, etc)
5. Click Next
6. In the tagger, drag and drop the tabs that correspond to your document fields
7. Click Finish
8. Before leaving the UI, return to your "Template" view and click on
   your template
9. Select the "i" icon, and save your templateId for later use.

Now that you have your template created, let's go ahead and quickly create an envelope that uses our new template.

```
POST /envelopes
{
    "status": "sent",
    "templateId": "00df08bf-xxx-xxx-xxx-ecaa2360c121",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "name": "Test User",
            "roleName": "signer",
            "routingOrder": "1",
        },
        {
            "email": "test2@test.com",
            "name": "EFG",
            "roleName": "cc",
            "routingOrder": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the only required information is templateID, status, and the recipient's information.

Comment: Thanks for this - I will read up on it and try it out and then let you know if it solves our use case.

Comment: OK, I tried that.  But it doesn't really address what I want to do.  I would like to be able to mark up a Word document with the signature locations, and other tags, including the information which is contained in your JSON example.  Maybe this part - the envelope - can be placed inside the document as plain text with a tag to identify it. Once the document is marked up like this, I would like to upload that document to DocuSign and not have to specify the envelope because it's all there in the document.  Does DocuSign support a use case like this?

Comment: I do not believe what you're describing is possible. The DocuSign object model goes something like this - the Envelope object contains documents, recipients, and tabs. A document (logically) cannot contain an envelope. There are some tricks to help you build your envelope properties (UI and API), such as including anchor strings in your document for more accurate placement. But you can't, for example, type DocuSign envelope properties into your docx file and expect DocuSign to parse that.

Comment: Thank you, @Matthew Roknich, that is the nice definitve answer I was looking for.  Not what I wanted to hear, but at least it makes the way forward for me very clear.

Answer (score 0):

reading this it sounds like you want your doc to auto-tag this info should help you on your way: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience

If not, the OOTB function within DocuSign templates you can create the tag (signature) on your word doc and save it in the DocuSign website where you will get the template ID that you can use.

Comment: Thanks!  I will read up on both the suggestions and come back to this post.

Comment: Please see my comment on Matthew Roknich's answer.